# extract from mssql using php scheduled task

Tags: php, sql-server, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I need to execute a scheduled task each minute that performs data extraction from MS Server.
Yet trying with bat script the php, would cause errors not recognizing sqlsrv functions

here is the content of the bat file:

```
cd C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
PHP C:\wamp\www\bin\Scripts\MinutelyScript.php
```

the `MinutelyScript.php` file works fine if executed from the server.
Please help me :)

Comment: checkout getting a url - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619088/windows-batch-file-file-download-from-a-url OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task-windows-task-scheduler

Comment: try running it locally `cd C:\wamp\www\bin\ ` then `PHP MinutelyScript.php` php should be in your include path

Comment: possibly duplicate? 

[PHP 5.3 not recognizing Native Client to connect to MS SQL][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824162/php-5-3-not-recognizing-native-client-to-connect-to-ms-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your batch file

```
//path to your website
cd \wamp\www\yourwebsite

c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php-cgi.exe -c  c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.ini -f cronfile.php
```

"cronfile.php" if file is at root folder if it is inner folder give path from root folder

Comment: accept the answer if it worked for you, All the best.
Happy Coding ;)